# Return Values from ID in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP structured like below. If I return the 'StateID' from a REST call, how can I use the ID to get the abbreviation and state name for that ID? For example an ID of '1' would return an abbreviation of Name = Alabama and Abbreviation = AL..

Array:

```
array(1) { ["StateList"]=> array(50) 
    { [0]=> array(3)
        { ["StateID"]=> int(1) ["Name"]=> string(7) "Alabama" ["Abbreviation"]=> string(2) "AL" } 
      [1]=> array(3) 
        { ["StateID"]=> int(2) ["Name"]=> string(6) "Alaska" ["Abbreviation"]=> string(2) "AK" }....
```

Comment: Loop through the array to find the entry you need.

Comment: `echo array_reduce($arr, function ($abbr, $state) { return $abbr ?: ($state['StateID'] == 1 ? $state['Abbreviation'] : null); })` - just because.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$id = 1; // Searched ID
foreach ($array['StateList'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['StateID'] == $id) {
        echo $value['Name'];
        echo $value['Abbreviation'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, just a matter of one simple loop.

---

PS. This is a linear solution. Of course You can make a function out of it:

```
function FindId($array, $id) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['StateID'] == $id) {
            return $value;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$result = FindId($array['StateList'], 1);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Just had to change $array to $array['StateList'], but your answer was 90% of the way there. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry, my fault! Thx for accept! I will correct it.